# Jsp Page Radio button changed property

Tags: jsp

I have radio buttons associated with text Box. If i change one radio button to another radio button the value of text field turns into * and disabled..
But at the same time Instead of value to text field, value of radio button is going to next jsp page because of this data is not showing .
Code is mentioned below:

```
             All Amount
            <input type="radio" onclick="changeAmountType(),p_gross_amount()" id="ASSIGN_TO_A" name="ASSIGN_TO" value="A"  /> 

              Specific  Amount
            <input type="radio" onclick="changeAmountType(),p_gross_amount()" id="ASSIGN_TO_S" name="ASSIGN_TO" value="S" checked /></font>
               </font></td>
                <td class=col6 >
                 <input type=text name="p_gross_amount_p" id="p_gross_amount" size="8" maxlength="20" value="" onkeypress='validate(event)' >
```

Comment: First thing, your question was not clear. Second, Post the necessary javascript codes (Especially changeAmountType(),p_gross_amount()) and post the code for how you are passing the values to next jsp page.

Comment: I dont want to send value of radio button to next page. I just want to send associated text box value to next jsp
 '      
function changeAmountType()
{
 if(document.getElementById('ASSIGN_TO_A').checked==true)
   {
   document.getElementById('p_gross_amount_p').disabled=true;
   document.getElementById('p_gross_amount_p').value='*';
   }
   else
   {
   document.getElementById('p_gross_amount_p').disabled=false;
   document.getElementById('p_gross_amount_p').value='';
   }
}

Comment: You wrong here, `p_gross_amount_p` is name. You need to take id such as **p_gross_amount** in your javascript function. Like this `document.getElementById('p_gross_amount').value='*';`